# ParsleyJS Custom Math Validators

Tags: parsley.js

I've successfully adapted parts of ParsleyJS to my needs in my form. Now I need to make some custom math validators, but I am struggling to figure out why my validators are not working.

What I need to accomplish:

Input 1: x

Input 2: can not be more than 10 different from x

an example form:

```
<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate="">

  <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" name="input1" required>

  <label for="input2">Input 2</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" name="input2" required data-parsley-not-more-than="input1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-validation-threshold="0">

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">

</form>
```

from the custom validator demo example I figured it'd be solved pretty easily like so:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('notMoreThan', {
  validateNumber: function(value, requirement) {
    return (value - requirement) <= 10;
  },
  requirementType: 'integer',
  messages: {
    en: 'This value can not be more than 10 different from %s'
  }
});
```

but.. Uncaught Requirement is not a integer: "input1"

fine. we'll change to a string then.

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('notMoreThan', {
  validateNumber: function(value, requirement) {
    return (requirement - value) <= 10;
  },
  requirementType: 'string',
  messages: {
    en: 'This value can not be more than 10 different from %s'
  }
});
```

but this always returns false, validation fails, whatever the input is.

then I look at the extras (greater than, less than or equal to) in the src/extra directory and they do this:

```
// gt, gte, lt, lte, notequalto extra validators
var parseRequirement = function (requirement) {
  if (isNaN(+requirement))
    return parseFloat(jQuery(requirement).val());
  else
    return +requirement;
};

// Greater than or equal to validator
window.Parsley.addValidator('gte', {
  validateString: function (value, requirement) {
    return parseFloat(value) >= parseRequirement(requirement);
  },
  priority: 32
});
```

So I guess, with my limited javascript knowledge, that they "interpret" the requirement value to return the right string if it's "not a number".

So, I try the same approach.

```
// gt, gte, lt, lte, notequalto extra validators
var parseRequirement = function (requirement) {
  if (isNaN(+requirement))
    return parseFloat(jQuery(requirement).val());
  else
    return +requirement;
};

// my not more than 10 different validator
window.Parsley.addValidator('notMoreThan', {
  validateString: function (value, requirement) {
    return ( parseFloat(value) - parseRequirement(requirement) ) <= 10;
  },
  priority: 32
});
```

But this always returns false as well.

I'm just at a complete loss. It may be my lack of javascript skills.. Hope this answer doesn't get downvoted for that. I'm trying to learn as best I can.

In conclusion, I need a solution to craft custom validators with simple math validations depending on fields. "Field B can be no more than X different from Field A" "Field D can not differ more than f from ((Field C divided by x) minus y)" and so on so on.

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution, hope it helps people who face similar issues, as documentation is lacking for newbies in this regard.

```
   window.Parsley.addValidator('notMoreThan', {
       validateNumber: function(value, requirement) {
           // requirement is passing the id of the input 1 so ve have to obtain the value of it
           var requirement_value = $('#'+requirement).val() ;
           return value - requirement_value <= 10  ;
       },
       requirementType: 'string',
       messages: {
           en: 'This value can not be more than 10 different from %s'
       }
   });
```

in order to make this work, we have to obtain the value of the requirement first. This is what was lacking.